# distributing pivot graphs to departments through email efficiently

Tags: workflow, excel-2010

I work at an institution with a lot of departments and subdivisions. I have an "excel-database" with pivotcharts that can show the results for the progress of the different departments and subdivisions, but there are quite a lot, and to get through all graphs (Dep 1, subdivision 1, Dep 1 subdivision 2, etc...) I have to go through quite a bunch of iterations sending out the graphs for each department and subdivision.

I'm considering creating a macro - that selects each option in the pivotchart and then exports to a word document, but I don't know if there's an easier way to go, since I guess thiss will take me quite some time too.

I'm thinking that someone probably has been in the same situation, so if anyone has any suggestions as to how this could be solved efficiently, please let me know.

**EDIT:** 
So as I see it there are three steps to this question that need solving (steps that are striked are steps that I know how to do)

1. Iterate through pivot table options
2. <strike>Copy charts to word OR other excel file and save</strike>
3. attach that file to a mail, and send it to the correct department-mail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general thinking about how to handle a case like yours has changed over the years.  Currently I would recommend making the data accessible on an internal website of some kind and allowing each department to generate their own graph on demand.  They would then be able to look at the data whenever they wanted and you would not have to send out graphs. See if Google  Drive or MS Office365 can do this for you.